# Kendo UI DropDownList undefined method Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, filter, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm trying to use .NET MVC Kendo DropDownList (Razor) with Filter functionality - as described on official Teleriks page here:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/serverfiltering.

My View contains:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("Product")
    .DataTextField("ProductName")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .Filter("startswith")
    .BindTo(Model.SchemataEnumerable)
    .Value(Model.SelectedSchemaId.ToString())
)
```

But when I run the page, the error message coming is :

> CS1061: 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DropDownListBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Filter' and no extension method 'Filter' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DropDownListBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can somebody help to solve this issue? What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try using "StartsWith" notice the capitals.

Answer (score 1):

If you did what I did, you forgot to link to the latest Kendo.Mvc.dll. Once I brought in the new dll everything worked fine.

Comment: Please add your suggestions in comments.

Comment: Uh, if it is a solution to the problem, why should it be a comment, instead of an answer?